# silverlight v.s. flash for video quality

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, flash, video

I heard Silverlight support high quality definition video, which flash does not support. Is that true? If yes, any other benefits comparing Silverlight to Flash?

If anyone could provide some document to make a reference, it will be appreciated!

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that "Flash does not support high quality definition video". They both support the same kind of high-quality video (H.264) so the question is moot.

The main different is that they support additional formats (e.g. Flash supports FLV with transparency, Silverlight supports proprietary MS formats).

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does supports video better then Flash but the two technologies are identical in many ways and in the end it probably comes down to whatever fit your needs.

For my point of view you get the really good tooling support and backend using Silverlight (VS2010, Expression Blend, C#) compared to Flash development.

Comment: "Silverlight does supports video better then Flash" -- I am interested to read more, any reference documents?

Comment: The only difference I can find is that Silverlight also supports some of the proprietary MS video formats (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx). Everything else seems pretty comparable. They both support HD video and audio. Flash has "Dynamic Streaming" (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/dynstream_advanced_pt1.html) and Silverlight has "Smooth Streaming" (http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/smoothstreaming/); they both support H.264; etc. But I would also be interested in knowing of other folks have found more significant differences.